# Cypher query for pair of nodes that are related to at least 2 other nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a problem where I need to find a count of nodes where a pair of same node type are both connected to.

so
(a1)--(b)
(a2)--(b)
(a1)--(c)
(a2)--(c)

The result I want to have is:
a1, a2, 2
[the pair of nodes I am looking at] and count how many other notes both of them relate to.

So far I have a query that gives me the nodes I need, but I am confused as to how can I form a 'pair' that I can then search for on the other related nodes.

Adding an example:
    CREATE
    (a1:Node {name: 'Alice'})-[:REFERS]->(b:Node {name: 'movie1'}),
    (a2:Node {name: 'Bob'})-[:REFERS]->(b),
    (a3:Node {name: 'Charlie'})-[:REFERS]->(b),
    (a3)-[:REFERS]->(d:Node {name: 'movie3'}),
    (a3)-[:REFERS]->(e:Node {name: 'movie4'}),
    (a1)-[:REFERS]->(c:Node {name: 'movie2'}),
    (a2)-[:REFERS]->(c);

The information I want to extract is what pair of actors were in a movie together, and a count of # of movies that pair of actors were in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. Creating your graph

With the additional information and requirements I want to suggest you an adapted graph, which takes the different roles `Actor` and `Movie` into account:

```
CREATE
  (alice:Actor {name: 'Alice'})-[:REFERS]->(movie1:Movie {name: 'Movie 1'}),
  (bob:Actor {name: 'Bob'})-[:REFERS]->(movie1),
  (charlie:Actor {name: 'Charlie'})-[:REFERS]->(movie1),
  (charlie)-[:REFERS]->(movie3:Movie {name: 'Movie 3'}),
  (charlie)-[:REFERS]->(movie4:Movie {name: 'Movie 4'}),
  (alice)-[:REFERS]->(movie2:Movie {name: 'Movie 2'}),
  (bob)-[:REFERS]->(movie2);
```

[image: example graph]

## 2. Realization

### 2.1 Requirement I

> "The information I want to extract is what pair of actors were in a
>   movie together [...]."

### 2.1.1 Solution

```
MATCH
  (movie:Movie)<-[:REFERS]-(actor:Actor)
RETURN
  movie.name AS movieName, collect(actor.name) AS actorTeam;
```

### 2.1.2 Result

```
╒═══════════╤═════════════════════════╕
│"movieName"│"actorTeam"              │
╞═══════════╪═════════════════════════╡
│"Movie 2"  │["Alice","Bob"]          │
├───────────┼─────────────────────────┤
│"Movie 1"  │["Alice","Bob","Charlie"]│
├───────────┼─────────────────────────┤
│"Movie 4"  │["Charlie"]              │
├───────────┼─────────────────────────┤
│"Movie 3"  │["Charlie"]              │
└───────────┴─────────────────────────┘
```

### 2.2 Requirement II

> "The information I want to extract is [...] a count of # of movies that
>   pair of actors were in."

### 2.2.1 Solution

```
MATCH
  (movie:Movie)<-[:REFERS]-(actor:Actor)
WITH
  movie.name AS movieName, collect(actor.name) AS actorTeam
RETURN
  actorTeam, count(actorTeam) AS movieAmount;
```

### 2.2.2 Result

```
╒═════════════════════════╤═════════════╕
│"actorTeam"              │"movieAmount"│
╞═════════════════════════╪═════════════╡
│["Alice","Bob","Charlie"]│1            │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│["Charlie"]              │2            │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│["Alice","Bob"]          │1            │
└─────────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

---

[Extension]

### 2.3 Requirement A (from comment)

> "'alice, bob' : 2, 'charlie, alice' : 1, 'charlie, bob' 1 (the ones
>   with 1 actor don't matter)"

### 2.3.1 Solution

```
MATCH
  (startActor:Actor)-[:REFERS]->(movie:Movie)<-[:REFERS]-(endActor:Actor)
  WHERE
  id(startActor) < id(endActor)
WITH
  startActor.name AS startActorName, endActor.name AS endActorName, count(movie) AS movieAmount
RETURN
  startActorName, endActorName, movieAmount;
```

The `id` comparison in the `WHERE` clause of line 4 avoids having two relationships per pair (one in each direction) and prevents creating the relationship from nodes to themselves.

### 2.3.2 Result

```
╒════════════════╤══════════════╤═════════════╕
│"startActorName"│"endActorName"│"movieAmount"│
╞════════════════╪══════════════╪═════════════╡
│"Alice"         │"Bob"         │2            │
├────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┤
│"Alice"         │"Charlie"     │1            │
├────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┤
│"Bob"           │"Charlie"     │1            │
└────────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: This is closer to what I need, however in the above example the pair of "Alice, Bob" has appeared in 2 movies together (movie 1 and movie 2). I've been stuck at this.

Comment: How would your desired result looks like ideally for the above created graph?

Comment: 'alice, bob' : 2,  'charlie, alice' : 1, 'charlie, bob' 1 (the ones with 1 actor don't matter)

Comment: Added an extension to the answer. See chapter "2.3 Requirement A".

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Can you please explain why does the id(startActor) < id(endActor) work? Does it simply filter out duplicate pairs where the 2nd actor is in the first place?

Comment: Exactly as you stated.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending the time on this

Answer (score 1):

### Creating your graph

For the ease of possible further answers and solutions I note my graph creating statement:

```
CREATE
  (a1:Node {name: 'a1'})-[:REFERS]->(b:Node {name: 'b'}),
  (a2:Node {name: 'a2'})-[:REFERS]->(b),
  (a3:Node {name: 'a3'})-[:REFERS]->(b),
  (a1)-[:REFERS]->(c:Node {name: 'c'}),
  (a2)-[:REFERS]->(c);
```

[image: example graph]

### Solution

```
MATCH
  (startNode:Node)-[:REFERS]-(endNode:Node)
WITH
  startNode.name AS inspectedNode, collect(endNode.name) AS pair
RETURN
  inspectedNode, pair, size(pair) AS pairAmount;
```

### Result

```
╒═══════════════╤════════════════╤════════════╕
│"inspectedNode"│"pair"          │"pairAmount"│
╞═══════════════╪════════════════╪════════════╡
│"a2"           │["b","c"]       │2           │
├───────────────┼────────────────┼────────────┤
│"c"            │["a1","a2"]     │2           │
├───────────────┼────────────────┼────────────┤
│"b"            │["a1","a2","a3"]│3           │
├───────────────┼────────────────┼────────────┤
│"a1"           │["b","c"]       │2           │
├───────────────┼────────────────┼────────────┤
│"a3"           │["b"]           │1           │
└───────────────┴────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: What I'm looking for is a bit different. The above basically gives me the count of relationships that each node has.  So if there is another node 'd' and 'e' connected to 'a3' - a3 doesn't have a 'pair', but the count above would show up as '3'

Comment: I need to be able to identify 'c' --> [a1, a2], 'b' -> [a1,a2]. None of the other nodes have 2x of the a* nodes

Comment: To develop a custom-fit solution, can you please detail under which circumstances a pair counts as pair? Can you please answer the following question in addition: Consists a pair exactly of two other nodes only or is `b`, `d` and `e` also a valid pair for `a3`?

Comment: Added an additional answer.